# Join two DBSet<T> in a LINQ expression in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, dbset

I need help join two DBSet in C# using LINQ expression (`Expression<Func<T, bool>>`).

I have a function FindByCondtion, which takes Expression> as an argument and returns IQueryable :

```
public IQueryable<T> FindByCondition(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
        {
            return this.RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Where(expression).AsNoTracking();
        }
```

So I want to write the below as `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` :

```
from d in device
  join db in deviceBranch on d.TerminalId equals db.TerminalId
  where db.BranchCode == branchCode
  select d
```

Your help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please note that Device and DeviceBranch are my two DBSets

Comment: Why do you want to use FindByCondition? Why not simply use the two DBSets and write the Join as you have?

Comment: The only part you could write as an `Expression` is the `where` clause, and that is easy: `db => db.BranchCode == branchCode` - that is all that is allowed by your `FindByCondition` method.